# Tkinter. subframe of root does not show

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys

class MapCreator:
    def __init__(self, root):
        #initialize the root window
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry('800x600+0+0')
        self.root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        self.menubar = None
        self.mapFrame = tk.Frame(self.root,bd = 2,bg = 'white')
        self.mapFrame.grid(column = 3, row = 3)
        #self.mapFrame.pack()
        self.__create_menubar()
    def __create_menubar(self):
        #Create the menubar
        self.menubar = tk.Menu()
        #config , which used to change the options
        self.root.configure(menu = self.menubar)

        #create a File menu and add it to the menubar
        #add a new menu
        file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=False)
        #File cascade
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
        #New
        file_menu.add_command(label="New", command=self.__create_new_map)
        #Open
        file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.__open_new_map)
        #Svae
        file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.__save_cur_map)
        #Save as
        file_menu.add_command(label="Save as", command=self.__saveas_cur_map)

    def __create_new_map(self):
        #if not saved , tell the editor
        pass

    def __open_new_map(self):
        #if not saved , tell the editor
        pass

    def __save_cur_map(self):
        #first time save or not
        pass

    def __saveas_cur_map(self):
        pass


    pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MapCreator(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I want to have a subframe to show other things. But I cannot find my subframe.

By the way, I'm not familiar with the `grid()` method.

So can someone tell me the reason why I cannot make the subframe show?

Comment: If you aren't familiar with grid, why are you using it, and why haven't you read the documentation on how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `tkinter` most of the widgets and frames take the default size when not specified. You can specify the size explicitly (give it a height and width) or have the frame or widgets stretch to dimensions.

Here is a brief introduction to tkinters grid and size. This is what I prefer, rather than specifying the height and weight.

Imagine you are splitting the Parent Frame (or any kind of container) into a grid. The grid attribute of the child allows you to position your child into the specific part of the Parent's grid. Like for example, you want your child to be in `(0,0)` of the parent. then you say. `child.grid(row=0, column = 0)`.

Note: You are not specifying the width and height of the grid. It re-sizes itself to the default size of the child widget. Button has a specific size. If the child is another frame and that frame is empty. It will not be visible because the size is 1px wide and 1px height.

rowspan, columnspan allows you to adjust how many rows or columns the child widget occupies. This is a similar concept to merging cells in Excel table. So when you say `child.grid(row=0, column = 0, rowspan=2, columnspan=2)` You are specifying that the widget is placed in `(0,0)` and occupies 2 rows and 2 columns.

Now that you have that, how do you make it stretch? This is done using stickys and weights. For the child widget, you specify the sticky. With this you are defining which directions you would like to stretch. `child.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky='ew')` specifies that the widget can stretch horizontally. `child.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky 'nsew')` specifies full stretch. Specifying the sticky does not stretch the widget, it just dictates what direction is can stretch. You specify the weight of the column and row of the parent grid to specify different levels of stretch. `parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` adds a weight of 1 to column 0. So column 0 is stretched. If you have multiple columns you want to stretch, then weight specifies the ratio of increase between those different columns. `parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` does the same for rows.

Given all that background. If you add the grid_rowconfigure and grid_columnconfigure to your root and add the sticky to your mapFrame. You get this:

```
def __init__(self, root):
    #initialize the root window
    self.root = root
    self.root.geometry('800x600+0+0')
    self.root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
    self.menubar = None
    self.mapFrame = tk.Frame(self.root,bd = 2,bg = 'white')
    self.mapFrame.grid(row = 0, sticky='nsew')
    self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    #self.mapFrame.pack()
    self.__create_menubar()
```

And this should work :)

There are lots of other properties you can specify in your `child.grid()` statement. The other one I usually use are `padx` `pady` which is padding in the x,y direction and `ipadx` `ipady` which is internal padding. Refer to http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm for more details

Answer (score 0):

Your frame *is* showing up. However, because it doesn't have anything in it, it's natural size is only one pixel wide and one pixel tall, making it virtually invisible.

Put something in the frame, or give it an explicit width and height.

Your other option is to configure grid such that the frame "sticks" to the sides of the cell it is in, and the cell expands to fill any extra space in the window.

For example:

```
self.mapFrame.grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky="nsew")
root.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
```