# Tkinter grid() alignment issue in python

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, rows, multiple-columns

I have been working in python for the first time and basically I am trying to get these to labels to align in the correct columns and the correct row but for some reason it doesn't move down rows and the columns are not correct either. Any help would be much appreciated!

CODE:

```
    from tkinter import *
    import sys

    #Setup GUI

    #Create main window
    main = Tk();
    #Create title of main window
    main.title = "Waterizer 1.0";
    #Create default size of main window
    main.geometry("1024x768");
    #Lets get a fram to stick the data in we plan on using
    mainApp = Frame(main);
    #Snap to grid
    mainApp.grid();
    #Font for main labels
    labelFont = ('times', 20, 'bold');
    #Label for the Power
    powerLabel = Label(mainApp, text="Power  Status");
    powerLabel.config(fg="Red", bd="1");
    powerLabel.config(font=labelFont);
    powerLabel.grid( row=0,column=20,columnspan=4, sticky = W);
    #Label for Water
    waterLabel = Label(mainApp, text="Water Status");
    waterLabel.config(fg="Blue", bd="1");
    waterLabel.config(font=labelFont);
    waterLabel.grid(row=20, column=20, columnspan=4, sticky = W);
```

Now I will attach an image for you guys to see how it displays... which is not correct :-(

[image: Issue with the grid.]

Comment: What was your desired output?

Comment: @Luke Willis Well the second label (in blue) should be dropped down further since it is 20 rows down and they should be scooted more to the middle of the screen since it is 20 columns in and not on column 0

Comment: What you could do is make empty `tk.Label()`'s to fill the gap, this may help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a row or column does not contain anything, it is then of size 1 pixel, which is very small. What you see in the output is actually the two text 20 rows apart. Add in widgets, and you will see your result.

You can also use `grid_rowconfigure`, `grid_columnconfigure` and `sticky` properties in order to specify how a widget in a grid stretches. That way you can place your widgets in the right screen locations.

Have a look at my answer here for more details on how to use grid properties: [Tkinter. subframe of root does not show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938465/tkinter-subframe-of-root-does-not-show/25939495#25939495)

To understand your grid better, I added another widget to you code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

#Setup GUI

#Create main window
main = Tk()
#Create title of main window
main.title = "Waterizer 1.0"
#Create default size of main window
main.geometry("1024x768")
#Lets get a fram to stick the data in we plan on using
mainApp = Frame(main)
#Snap to grid
mainApp.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
#main grid stretching properties
main.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
main.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
#Font for main labels
labelFont = ('times', 20, 'bold')
#Label for the Power
powerLabel = Label(mainApp, text="Power  Status")
powerLabel.config(fg="Red", bd="1")
powerLabel.config(font=labelFont)
powerLabel.grid( row=0,column=20, sticky = W)
#Label for Water
waterLabel = Label(mainApp, text="Water Status")
waterLabel.config(fg="Blue", bd="1")
waterLabel.config(font=labelFont)
waterLabel.grid(row=20, column=20, sticky = W)
#ScrollText to fill in between space
ScrollText = ScrolledText(mainApp)
ScrollText.grid(row=1, column=20,sticky = 'nsew')
#mainApp grid stretching properties
mainApp.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
mainApp.grid_columnconfigure(20, weight=1)

main.mainloop()
```

Try this.

PS: You do not need `;` after every line python

Answer (score 4):

Empty rows have a height of zero, and empty columns have a width of zero. Grid is behaving as designed with your code, since there are no widgets in rows 1-19, and no widgets in columns 0-19. Put something in the other rows and columns and your labels will move.