# Tkinter gui mainloop "ex ="

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hello I'm a complete beginner in python and facing a problem while creating a simple gui in tkinter (trying to make simple Pong). Anyways I have this code in python 3:

```
    from tkinter import Frame
import tkinter

class Pong(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.bind("<Key>", self.key)
        self.initialize()

    def key(self, event):
        if event.char == 'q':  #end
            self.quit()
        print("end")
    def initialize(self):
        print("initialize")
        pass

def main():

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    ex = Pong(root)
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

I'm wondering what specifically does the bottom "ex = Pong(root)" part do because if I delete that the program doesn't work, I cant press Q to quit, but I can't find what ex means, I literally can't find documentation online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Pong** class is a Wrapper Frame. It represents the GUI application, and encapsulates (hides away) the Tkinter GUI stuff.

A **Frame** is a "window" the content is shown in. *root* is a **Tk** master frame. *root* is the base window - destroying root destroys (closes) the GUI.

with that in mind, I recommend trying the following changes:

```
class Pong(Frame):

...

    def key(self, event):
        if event.char == 'q':  #end
            # close the base Frame, and our application Frame
            self.parent.quit()
            self.quit()

    # wrapper methods for root control
    def overrideredirect( bool ):
        self.parent.overrideredirect(bool)

    def geometry(geo_string):
        self.parent.geometry(geo_string)

    def mainloop():
        self.parent.mainloop()

...

def main():

    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    wdth, hght = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    ex = Pong(root)
    ex.overrideredirect(True)
    ex.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(wdth, hght))
    ex.mainloop()
```

You can then drive the master window using Pong. I used this approach before and found it safer - I didn't confuse root with my Frame class and make nasty accidents! Also it is safer than subclassing Tk.

Also you could add a method to pong, **generate_gui()**, and code it to setup your GUI widgets. this is also safer than setting up the widgets from the main function directly.

Check out these in the meantime:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
```

This creates a toplevel widget of Tk which usually is the main window of an application.

```
ex = Pong(root)
```

Pong is a class that creates a widget (`ex`) of type `Frame` that has a certain characteristics defined by you in the `Pong` class. All widgets need a parent widget that it can be bound to. Here you are creating a child widget `ex` of type `Pong` bound to `root`.

```
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
root.mainloop()
```

Here you are telling the parent widget what size it should be and where should its origin be. (Full screen and 0,0). Note that you have not mentioned what size and where you child widget `ex` needs to be inside `root`. You can do so using tkinter's geometry - `grids` or `pack` (More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26225122/3646530) Since `ex` does not really have any graphics and your interaction is only key binding, you dont have to worry about that yet.

When you do press, `q` you expect the window to quit. The Frame widget might quit, but you also need the root widget to destroy itself. So something like this works.

```
class Pong(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.bind("<Key>", self.key)
        self.initialize()

    def key(self, event):
        if event.char == 'q':  #end
            self.quit()
        print("end")


    def quit(self):
        self.parent.destroy() 

    def initialize(self):
        print("initialize")
        pass
```

For details on tkinter's widgets and functions you try here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. I have almost completed my first version of the program